# PHP & Mysql : PHP filtering query from database over a list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a jQuery list which is returning a list of user_name on php page like

**rohit,Bhalu,Ram**

Now I want to filter the user_names from the database which is not the part of above list

So far I am trying the basic query of mysql like

```
 select * from table_name where user_name NOTIN('rohit','Bhalu','Ram');
```

But problem with above query is, this a not the specific solution for bigger list which contains 1000 user_name so I want to use some query filter with php

Please suggest me what should I do in this stage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use index for field user_name.

Second use this query (in $array - usernames)

```
$array = array('Rohit', 'Bhalu');
$comma_separated = implode("','", $array);
$comma_separated = "'".$comma_separated."'";
$query = "select * from table_name where user_name NOT IN($comma_separated)";
```

Comment: CREATE INDEX key_user_name ON table_name (user_name);

Comment: ok now my $array = Array
(
    [0] => rohit
    [1] => Bhalu
)                   but still its not working for me